# flask blueprints list routes

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, blueprint

I have a flask app with the below tree:

```
root/
  - modules/
    __init__.py
    - common/
        __init__.py
    - citrixlb/
        __init__.py # blueprint code
        citrixlb.py # module class
    - aws/
        __init__.py # blueprint code
        aws.py      # module class
```

So I would like to know, is there a way to dynamically list all routes for all blueprints?

I have this in my `root/__init__.py`:

```
# import our modules
from modules.citrixlb import *
from modules.aws import *

app.register_blueprint(aws)
app.register_blueprint(citrix)
```

If I can dynamically list all routes for all blueprints, I can auto generate the links.

Example:

DropDown: `AWS`

- `/aws`
- `/aws/ec2`
- `/aws/subnets`

Comment: Have you seen this: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/117/?

Comment: @esdes close enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

```
def get_bp_urls(blueprint):
    from flask import Flask
    temp_app = Flask(__name__) 
    temp_app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
    return [str(p) for p in temp_app.url_map.iter_rules()]
```